# Limit of a function with two floor functions in the expression

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The sum property of limits can only be applied when the limits exist, right? As follows:

$$
\lim_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)] = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a} g(x)
$$

But only if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ exist simultaneously. Then, how to find the following limit

$$\lim_{x \to 2} (\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor -x \rfloor)$$

knowing that both of them doesn't exist?

Is there a way to manipulate the expression? I'm not familiar with floor functions.

Comment: Did you try substituting $x=1.99$ and $x=2.01$ to get a feeling for what's going on?

Comment: That's true! I didn't even think about computing the values manually. So there's no way I can prove this using properties and whatnot?

Comment: To be more specific, I'm being asked to prove that the limit exists.

Comment: Have you tried finding the limits individually from different directions of $2$?

Comment: @DatBoi hmmm gonna do that, brb

Comment: @Gabriel The first step should be getting a feeling for what's going on. After you have a guess for why the limit exists you can formalize your argument, but it would be hard without first getting a feel for it.

Comment: You can also plot the function near 2. It is basically a constant function with jump discontinuities at every integer.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The analytical way of proving the limit exists was by approaching it from both directions as @DatBoi suggested.